# Fetch multiple rows with MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, rows, multiple-instances

If I have a MySQL query that looks like this:

```
SELECT Content FROM AP_Data WHERE Title='Featured' or Title='Carousel'
```

Is it possible to use PHP to then turn the variables into something like

```
echo $Row['Featured']['Content'];
echo $Row['Carousel']['Content'];
```

I hope that by doing this, I can save time without bombarding the server with multiple queries. This is only a snippet of the queries I require.

Comment: first you `select content` not all columns , replace `select content` by `select *`  , and this is not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First lets update your query to include the **Title** field.

```
SELECT Content, Title FROM AP_Data WHERE Title='Featured' or Title='Carousel'
```

When looping through results you can build the array to suit your needs

```
<?php
while($row = your_query_result){

  //If you have one Content per Title   
  $array[$row['Title']] = $row['Content'];

  //If you have multiple Contents per Title
  $array[$row['Title']][] = $row['Content'];

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Featured` and `Carousel` are not column names , they just values in columns.

you can do this instead.

```
    SELECT Content,Title FROM AP_Data WHERE Title='Featured' or Title='Carousel'
```

and the code

```
if  ($Row['Title'] == 'Featured') 
    {echo $Row['Content']; // content of featured
    } 
else{
    echo $Row['Content']; //content of carousel
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not work that way. But if you add Title to your query, like so:

```
SELECT Title,Content FROM AP_Data WHERE Title='Featured' or Title='Carousel'
```

You can then build an array like that. You can also do an ORDER BY Title so that all of the Carousel results would be first.